# update email in textfield as a person field for access reasons

Tags: sharepoint-online

i have a flow with a text field where i have as a default value an email address. (person fields cannot have default values)

unfortunately i cannot use this value to grant access to item or a folder.

how can i achive that  the email in the textfiled is "converted" to a person field or at least to give access to that emailaddress at the end of the flow?
i don´t wanna use powerapps...

thanks

kurt

Comment: In flow, you can get user ID from that particular site collection using email via SharePoint REST API & then use the user ID to grant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string variable to store the single line email address, then send the email using variable:

[image]